# How to add “Sales by role” to Woocommerce reports or Filter by role to complete order report

Tags: woocommerce, hook-woocommerce

In  Woocommerce reports page we want to add filter "Sales by role" to Report or if may be any particular role wise filter report data to show in admin report section, where to find total sale amount by that role, also we need which product and how much quantity in each order product have.